# Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, liquibase

I am working on a WebApp with Vaadin and Hibernate which is using Version 3.2.3 of Liquibase as a dependency.

When I build this App and test it with the Tomcat7 Maven Plugin everything works fine.

When I deploy the .war file manually to Azure (running Tomcat 8.5) or a Tomcat 8.5 on my local machine I get the following error:

`liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger`

When I deploy the .war manually to a Tomcat 7.0 running locally it works again.

The database is the same in all cases.

What might be the reason for this?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a should-be-fixed-but-still-reproduced issue.

There are two issues in Liquibase's Jira:

- [CORE-2003](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2003)
- [CORE-2042](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2042)

Try updating liquibase. Version 3.2.3 is very old already.

Comment: I updated to 3.8.0, now I get an error in the log files concerning the xml schemes, which doesn't seem to crash the program though the app seems to work on my local Tomcat Servers.
On Azure I get a new error message. I posted that as an update.
I don't know if this is a completely different problem and I should make a new post and close this one though.

Comment: I think it's a different problem. Looks like liquibase can not parse your databaseChangeLog.